# When i run the scrapy its shows an error like __import__(name) ImportError: No module named home in ubuntu

Tags: python, django, django-models, web-scraping, scrapy

when i run the scrapy it shows an error like, **import**(name) ImportError: No module named home,how to solve this issue?

```
import os
import sys
import django

DJANGO_PROJECT_PATH = '/home/user/Documents/myproject'
DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE = 'myproject.settings'

sys.path.insert(0, DJANGO_PROJECT_PATH)
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE
BOT_NAME = 'example_bot'

django.setup()
```

Comment: The code section is irrelevant to your question

Comment: Please, provide the traceback from the exception, and the lines from your code that trigger the exception.